# Start Juggernaut and Redis with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, juggernaut

I'm developing a app with Ruby on Rails.  It uses juggernaut.  Is there anyway I can get redis and juggernaut to start when I run `rails server`. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but a better way is to use software designed for the purpose, such as [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html). It's a Ruby program for running and monitoring processes alongside your web app and is very easy to configure, plus it exports to upstart and init, either of which you're likely to be using in production. Take a look, I think you'll like it.